# Pork shoulder put in broken oven for 10 hours, safe to eat?

Tags: pork

So I didn't realize my oven was broken until 10 hours after I had my pork shoulder in there. I realized it and then cooked it for 16 hours at 220F. What are the risks of eating this after 16 hours of cooking?

Comment: Are you saying that the shoulder sat in a room-temp oven for 10 hours?

Comment: @logophobe yes. Maybe even 12 hours at about 90-100F and then cooked.

Comment: You may want to see here, then: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/34670/25059

Comment: This might be a duplicate, but it looks like we have found a new reason for pre-heating an oven.